# Cyanogenmod android.jar file

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I'm attempting to write an application which uses a few classes and constants that were added to cyanogenmod and do not exist within the standard andriod api.

My question is, using the android SDK, eclipse and ADT, is it possible to get and build against a cyanogenmod version of the andriod.jar file?

Comment: Check out [this blog post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) to see how to fool ADT and use a modified version of android.jar.

Comment: That actually helps quite a bit, the only piece I'm missing now is how to get the actual android.jar from cyanogenmod to use as the "replacement" in that post. Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else ends up in this situation.

Since the andriod.jar file which is used during compilation is basically a set of stubs, I created a separate jar file of my own, with stubbed out versions of the necessary classes & constants, and included that class at compile time for my app (using maven scopes in my case).